# Cannot pass List to rule as a parameter

Tags: prolog

I need to pass a list as a third argument to the rule `find/3`. But I am getting `ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated`. What's wrong?

Code:

```
find(A,B, DepartureTime):-
    % .....

find(_,_,_):-
    % do stuff
```

The query:

```
?-find('Moscow','NY', [6,0]).
```

Comment: The problem is somewhere in "do stuff" or "....." since I don't see where you're showing the use of `is`. For `is` to work, *all* of the arguments to the right of `is` must be instantiated. For example, if you have, `X is Y + Z`, then both `Y` and `Z` must be instantiated.

Comment: I have some methods in find which goes into recursion. When I try to `debug` with graphical debugger of SI-Prolog it shows error in root element being called in this case: `find(A,B, DepartureTime)`. How can  I trace exact location of the error?

Comment: use `?- leash(-all).` then `?- trace.`

Comment: SOLVED. Credit goes to @mbratch.